# Wait for method with completion block to finish inside fast enumeration block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I know I could use a for loop iteration with an incrementing variable, then increment that on success, but since blocks are faster I'd like to use them ideally. The method inside the for loop is processed in the background and creates threads and sockets which slows it down so I'd like to wait for it to finish before moving to the next. Here is the code below.

```
    for (NSString *uuid in file_assets) {
        if (![asset_model isFileUploaded:uuid]) {
            [self uploadFileAssetWithUUID:uuid :^(BOOL success){

                if (success) {
                    NSLog(@"Upload finished..");
                }

            }];
        }
    }
```

How do I communicate inside the block to move the next iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait, and don't want to wait. Queue. Use an `NSOperationQueue` to create all of the uploads and control how many run concurrently. If you try to make your loop wait then any speed advantage you think you are obtaining is invalidated and you risk blocking the main thread.

Comment: Makes sense! I didn't even think of using queues, but it's probably a better fit for this kind of computation. Thank you.

Comment: Has this answer ceased to be a solution to your problem @LibanAbdulle?

Comment: Hi, no I just wanted to delete my account and history.

Comment: Why? Lots of your questions have answers and some have lots of views so are of benefit to the community. I mean delete if you want, but please consider your position in the community first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use dispatch queue for this purpose. I think it can meet your needs

```
dispatch_queue_t exampleQueue = dispatch_queue_create( "NewQueue", NULL );
dispatch_async(exampleQueue, ^{
// do your upload....

dispatch_queue_t queue=dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

do your update after upload

});
});
```